# How to check if the date is in range with out having a year set in objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

Is there a way to check if NSDate object is in the range of month day with out having a year set in range.  For example I have NSDate eqaual to February 2 1956 and I want find out if that date is in range between January 10 and February 10 within any year.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`.

e.g.

```
// Assuming 'data' is a valid NSDate object
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSMonthCalendarUnit+NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger day = components.day;
NSInteger month = components.month;
if ( (month>=startMonth && month<=endMonth) && (day>=startMonthDay && day<=endMonthDay)) {
// do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];` (The `+` have been replaced with a `|`.)

Comment: @Yan one thing to note, however, is that if the current user calendar changes, the above code may or may not be correct.

Comment: No. Equal same thing. They are bit fields, not consecutive values. It is perfectly correct. (So, yes, your suggestion works equally as well, but it doesn't matter for correctness)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `-compare` message, or, use `-timeIntervalSince1970`

```
NSDate *startRange;
NSDate *endRange;

// method one
if (([myDate compare:startRange] > 0) &&  ([myDate compare:endRange] < 0))
{
    // execute code here
}

// method two
if (myDate.timeIntervalSince1970 > startRange.timeIntervalSince1970 && 
    myDate.timeIntervalSince1970 < endRange.timeIntervalSince1970)
{
     // execute code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html) instance and use the components:forDate: method, then extract the month and date components from the resulting [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSDateComponents for this

```
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    // setting units we would like to use in future
    unsigned units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
    // creating NSCalendar object
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    // extracting components from date
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:date];

    if (components.month <= 2 && components.month >= 1) {
         if (components.month == 2) {
                if (components.day <= 10) {
                       // Date is in range
                }
         } else if (components.month == 2) {
                if (components.day >= 10) {
                       // Date is in range
         }
    }
```